# Not able to get debugger in "com.vaadin.client.ApplicationConnection" class

Tags: google-chrome, gwt, intellij-idea, vaadin, vaadin7

My application is throwing an exception from "com.vaadin.client.ApplicationConnection" class of vaadin 7.4.6 and i want to debug this class to exactly identify the issue.

I'm using IntellijIdea IDE and I'm able to debug the classes in the "com.vaadin.server" package but not in "com.vaadin.client" through Super Dev mode.

Do we need to do anything special for debugging in the "com.vaadin.client" package.

Comment: You can debug the Java code directly in Chrome, if you go to Developer Tools (F12) -> Sources, with "Enable JavaScript source maps" in the Settings. I'd also like to know how to debug in IntelliJ, it would be some setup related to http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/09/intellij-idea-14-brings-better-gwts-super-dev-mode-support/

Comment: @sreg Thank you Sreg, Yes I figured out how to debug it from intellij. I did wanted non super dev mode as super dev mode was not helping me to debug the java code in the Intellij corresponding to each Javascript.